# C: Ignoring a specific character, while using fscanf

Tags: c

As an example I have a text file that includes this text: `"name?"`

I want to save this String only as `name?`

I tried `("%["]")`, but this doesn't work.

Which function should I use?

Answer (score 2):

[The `scanf` and `fscanf` functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) work exactly the same. Your format is however wrong.

Try instead e.g. `"\"%[^\"]\""` as your format.

The first and last `"` is to mark the start and end of the string. Inside the string one can't use plain double-quote as that will end the string. So these have to be escaped using the backslash.

If we break down the format string into its three main components:

- `\"` - This matches the literal double-quote
- `%[^\"]` - This matches a string *not* containing the double-quote (the negation is what the `^` does)
- Lastly `\"` again, to match the end quote of your input

Comment: This is basically OK; these notes are nitpicking.  I'm not sure if it is worth noting that (with this format string) there's no way to know whether the terminal double quote is matched or not — `scanf()` won't tell you. Other formats could. The `%[^\"]` pattern is vulnerable to buffer overflowing; if there isn't a closing double quote, it will scan the rest of the file, newlines, blanks, and all. I would probably include at least newline in the negated scan set. It would probably be a good idea to apply the appropriate length limit (e.g. `%255[^\"\n]` if the variable is `char buffer[256];`).